# .htaccess RewriteRule for clean URLs is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm finishing up with a blog for a client that was basically written from scratch. The client's site is set up under shared hosting, with this particular site being located at the physical address:

```
/public_html/example.com
```

A post from the blog currently looks like this:

```
example.com/blog/viewpost.php?id=14
```

When it needs to look like this:

```
example.com/blog/title-of-blog-post
```

The below is the current .htaccess file, located at `/public_html/example.com`

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .html .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ /blog/viewpost.php?id=$1 [R=301]
```

No other PHP `$_GET` parameters are passed to `viewpost.php` other than `$_GET['id']`, which is used with a mySQL query to grab the details of the blog post from the database. This line of code is used to convert the title of the blog post into a URL-safe title:

```
$new_title = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row['postTitle']));
```

I'm pretty sure my .htaccess file is incorrect and I couldn't find anything around here to help me work through this, could somebody take a look?

Comment: Just to confirm, your application already links to URLs of the form `/blog/title-of-blog-post` (the pretty version)? You appear to need the ID to rewrite to the real URL, however, this does not appear in the "pretty" URL, so where is the ID expected to come from?

Comment: No, the URL is currently of the form `site.com/blog/viewpost.php?id=14` and needs to be of the form `site.com/blog/title-of-post`. Do I have something backward in the RewriteRule?

Comment: In that case the first thing to do is change the URLs in your app to be of the "pretty" form that you want your users to see. (Since you have code to calc a URL-safe title I thought you might have been doing this already, but your comments suggested otherwise.) You then use mod_rewrite to rewrite the "pretty" URL back to the "ugly" (real) URL, which is sort of what you are doing in .htaccess (although the ID doesn't match up). Since you need the ID to generate the real URL, this really needs to be part of the "pretty" URL. eg. `/blog/title-of-blog-post-14` or `/blog/14-title-of-blog-post`.

Comment: If you don't change the URLs in your application to the new "pretty" (virtual) URL then the "ugly" URL is still visible for users to see and copy. And every time a user follows a link on your site they will be need to be _redirected_ (2 HTTP requests) to the "pretty" URL (which would also need to be implemented in .htaccess).